# I fixed my question 3 times, please suggest how to reword it

Tags: discussion

I changed my [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17612/why-is-the-wall-in-tijuana-such-a-big-problem-for-migrants/17617?noredirect=1#comment44724_17617) many times, to please Rory, but it's still not good enough. He even disabled the reopen button. Please edit the question or make a suggestion. My opinion is, that he does not want my question to appear in whatever form, period.

Comment: The problem is that your question is roughly analogous to a climbing wall question where the wall is the Berlin Wall.  Technically the Berlin Wall was not difficult to climb, it was that people really did not want you to climb it.  The situation is much less extreme at Tijuana, but it is still a quasi-military question and this site has no expertise in evading military patrols.

Comment: I see it as an element, nature evading question. The wall has no significance as it is easy to evade, but there's the possibility of drowning.

Comment: The Berliners would fire on you, so evading them was relevant, but border patrol won't, so they are not so relevant, that's my rationale. They'll rather take you to jail.

Comment: No to mention we are talking about the whole ocean and Berlin was an urban space, not outdoors at all.

Comment: Parkour is on topic.  Climbing the Berlin Wall would be parkour under fire, and would be off topic.  Your question is basically how to outflank a military operation, and that is not on topic.  Ask how to go from A to B  on the open ocean safely with minimal equipment  -- on topic.  Add in evading the border patrol -- off topic.

Comment: I changed the question yet again as per suggestion.

Comment: No - your update did not touch on the problems that question has with scope.

Comment: I made another [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/17635/boating-along-the-coast-of-the-pacific), only you folks know point A is Tijuana :)))

Answer (score 4):

You have not fixed your question. You have changed it from one off topic reason to now have even more problems. I have also not disabled the reopen button (and in fact have no way to do that)

Your opinion is incorrect - None of the mods close questions because we don't want them to appear. We close because they fail to meet site requirements, or the community flags them.

The problem you have is that the question is not suited to this site. If you read the [about] and [ask] pages you will have a better idea why. And if you can make it fit our site guidelines it can be reopened.

Right now it's a shopping recommendation question - very offtopic - and too broad.

**UPDATE**: You are not listening to the community here. Your update still fails to address the issue. The question is not on topic here. If you read the [about] and [ask] pages you will see why. I have deleted the question. Your current activity shows you are not improving it, so your basic premise is not going to work here. If you have a future question that meets guidelines, please do ask it, but for this one, you will be better off going to another site, not Stack Exchange.

Comment: you still did not make any suggestions or edits while I made many already.

Comment: @user1095108 I have started the vote to delete your question. I looked at the new edits, and the whole line of thought is just not appropriate for this site.  There is nothing "wrong" with your question, the problem is that you have picked the wrong place to ask it.  And as a follow-up I don't think there  is a right place in the StackExchange family of sites to ask it.

Comment: @JamesJenkins once again, completely without justification, despite my best efforts to change my question.